# Why does the principle of superpositions not seem to work in this case? Please help me understand this better without a proof.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just learned about the principle of superpositions and I tried it with a simple example from physics which led to questionable results...

$$y''(t) = g = 9.8\text{ m/s}^2\iff y'(t) = gt + c_1\iff y(t) = \frac12 gt^2 + c_1 t + c_2$$

If I take two specific solutions; say for $y_1$, $c_1 = 2$, $c_2 = 0$ and for $y_2$, $c1 = 3, c2 = 4$; when I add $Ay_1 + By_2$ (where A, B are constants), I end up with a term $(A + B)(\frac12 gt^2)$. This would imply that one solution to $y''(t) = g$ involves a term where the coefficient to $t^2$ is not $1/2$! This seems like a contradiction because I know that the constant in front of $t^2$ for the position with constant acceleration function is always $\frac12 g$. Where did I go wrong? Am I misunderstanding the principle of superposition?

I may just have tunnel vision and/or have made a mistake, but I can't seem to find it. Sorry in advance!

Comment: What you're saying "principle of superposition" is basically saying it is a homogeneous linear DE: a linear combination of solutions is also a solution. The ODE in question is not. $$y_1''=g~\land~y_2''=g\implies (ay_1+by_2)''=(a+b)g\neq g$$

Comment: Here's one statement of the Superposition Principle: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/first-order-linear-odes/MIT18_03SCF11_s4_5text.pdf ... In that explanation you cannot just superimpose two solutions of $y''=g,$ but you can superimpose solutions of $y''=Ag$ and $y''=Bg$ and get a solution of $y''=(A+B)g,$ which indeed correctly has the $t^2$ term $\frac12(A+B)gt.$

Comment: The previous comment may be hard to relate to the explanation of the Superposition Principle that you received. Different authors express it differently. Perhaps if you would edit your question to show exactly how the principle was given to you, someone could explain the misunderstanding.

Comment: @DavidK Wait but that was the whole point; y(t) cannot be (A + B)(1/2)gt^2 + ... Prasun Biswas mentioned that my example isn't linear, so that would completely clear up my confusion. I think I'm using the theorem correctly and perhaps you're a little mistaken. By correctly, I don't mean in the right context though (as Prasun Biswas pointed out). Sorry if I'm wrong, but would you tell me what you think?

Comment: $y(t)$ certainly well **can** be $\frac12(A+B)gt$ if the equation is $y''=(A+B)g.$ In fact it must be. That is how MIT Open Courseware teaches Principle of Superposition. But there are other ways to state the principle that look very different. So why don't you take the advice I already gave and show us (in the question) how **your** instructor taught it. We can't explain what we have not seen.

Comment: Also, have you noticed how everyone else's formulas look like a textbook while yours are almost unreadable? You too can have formulas that people can easily read: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I'm sorry... let me do my best to present it to you in a readable format:                                                         If $y_2(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are both solutions of the linear homogeneous equation $$P(x)d^2y/dx^2 + Q(x)dy/dx + R(x)y = 0$$ and $c_1, c_2$ are any constants, then the function $y(x) = c_1y_1(x) + c_2y_2(x)$ is also a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To restate the principle as you learned it:

> If $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are both solutions of the linear homogeneous equation
> $$ P(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+Q(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+R(x)y=0, \tag1$$
> and $c_1,c_2$ are any constants, then the function $y(x)=c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x)$ is also a solution.

So let's now consider the differential equation
$$ y''(t) = g. \tag2$$
Since $y''(t)$ is just another notation for $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2},$
or in the format of Equation $(1),$
another way to write Equation $(2)$ is

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = g. \tag3$$

So let's compare this to Equation $(1)$. We see the coefficient of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is just $1,$ so we must have $P(x)=1.$ The $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $y$ terms are missing, so we must have $Q(x)=R(x) = 0.$

Now the only remaining terms to match up are the $0$ on the right-hand side of $(1)$ and the $g$ on the right-hand side of $(3)$. If $g = 0$ then $(3)$ is an equation in the same form as $(1)$, the Principle of Superposition applies, and any linear combination of solutions of $(3)$ is a solution of $(3).$

If $g \neq 0$ then you don't have an equation in the form of Equation $(1)$ and you cannot use the principle.

A familiar example from physics that **does** work is a mass suspended from a perfect Hooke's Law spring with constant $k$:

$$  y''(t) + k y(t) = 0. $$

Try the Principle of Superposition on a couple of solutions of that equation.

Comment: Ah... my example was not homogeneous. You made me realize that the g is really just f(x) in the non-homogeneous case because it's not a coefficient of some derivative of y or y itself. Thank you so much for your time.